# .net core Avoid repeating ModelState in controller/action

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-core, modelstate

Im working in a .net core 2.x project.
I write below code in each action to validate my modelstate.

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Return Modelstate Error
        }
```

I want to know what is the best practice to avoid repeating the condition in each action. 
I want to validate modelstate before reaching the action and return the appropriate error message if modelstate is not valid.

**Update**

Note. My actions are simple Api action and I just want to return errors ( which are in my Model)in the HttpContext Body in the form of array of string.

Eg of Model Property.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill the name Please !!!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Eg of Action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Create([FromBody]MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Return Modelstate Error
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this out https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/validation-response-aspnet-core-webapi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try somethink like this

```
 public class ModelStateValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string ErrorPage;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {


 if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //return error result
            List<string> list = (from modelState in context.ModelState.Values from error in modelState.Errors select error.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(list);

            //or redirect to some result
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(ErrorPage);

            //or do whatever you need
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

and add it like this

on controller

```
[ModelStateValidationFilter(ErrorPage = "somepage")]
    public class SomeController : Controller
```

on action

```
[ModelStateValidationFilter(ErrorPage = "somepage")]
public IActionResult SomeAction(somemodel model)
```

or add to all via startup

Comment: Thanks for your response. my actions are simple Api , there are not IActionResult and I want just return array of errors ( which are describe in my model ) in my HttpContext. I don't want to return an error page.

Comment: @Arashbahreini do you need an example with api? or will this example enough?